# Create IPA: provisioning profile on pom.xml

Tags: ios, maven, provisioning-profile, gluon-mobile

I am using maven and gluon to create my IPA. I would like to know if it is possible to set the provisioning profile in pom.xml, without using xcode?

Sorry, I wanted to ask for a slightly different thing.
I have two provisionon profiles, one for production (to publish the app) and one for development (for tests and the mvn run).
From: developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates, download and install the production provisioning and then the development provisioning. So both certificates are present in the ~ / Library / MobileDevice / Provisioning Profiles folder.
I run the mvn build and when I try to run the mvn run I have an error for the missing provisioning development.
Vicerverse if I download and install the provisiong dev first and then the production one, I repeat the build, this time the run works but the publication does not.
How can I manage both profiles without deleting the tests from the ~ / Library / MobileDevice / Provisioning Profiles each time and modifying the pom.xml?
Thanks a lot for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Gluon [Client plugin](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin) for Maven, you'll see some options that can be added to the plugin configuration.

Usually, the IDE helps finding out these options or you can [check the code](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/NativeBaseMojo.java) to find them.

To sign your iOS app, you can use:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.15</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
        ...
        <IOSSigningIdentity>iPhone Distribution: ***</IOSSigningIdentity>
        <IOSProvisioningProfile>*****</IOSProvisioningProfile>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, build the native image with

```
mvn client:link
```

you can run:

```
mvn client:package
```

to build the signed IPA.

Anyway, these plugin extensions should be explained in the plugin's readme )I filed an issue for that).